# Gender of a song in sql

Tags: mysql, hive

I need to find if a song is followed by male or Female or both

Table UserSongs

```
user_id               song
......                .....
1                     song1
2                     song1
3                     song2
4                     song3
```

Table Users

```
user_id         gender
......          ......
1               male 
2               female
3               male
4               female
```

Expected output:

```
Song            gender
....            ......
song1           Both 
song2           Male
song3           Female
```

I am using the following query

```
SELECT
    us.song_name,
    u.gender
FROM
    UserSongs us
    LEFT JOIN Users u ON us.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    [inner].song,
    CASE
        WHEN [inner].countMale = 0 AND [inner].countFemale > 0 THEN 'Female'
        WHEN [inner].countMale > 0 AND [inner].countFemale = 0 THEN 'Male'
        WHEN [inner].countMale > 0 AND [inner].countFemale > 0 THEN 'Both'
        ELSE                                                   THEN 'None'
    END AS gender
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            song,
            COUNT( CASE WHEN gender = 'Male'   THEN 1 END ) AS countMale,
            COUNT( CASE WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END ) AS countFemale
        FROM
            UserSongs
            INNER JOIN Users ON UserSongs.user_id = Users.userid
        GROUP BY
            song
    ) AS [inner]
```

To exclude the "None" rows, add this clause to the very end of the outer-query:

```
WHERE
    [inner].countMale > 0
    OR
    [inner].countFemale > 0
```

(You cannot check for `gender <> 'None'` because the `SELECT` clause is evaluated after the `WHERE` clause: an entire SQL `SELECT` statement is not listed in evaluation order, frustratingly)